# virtualenv: uninstall and reinstall on macos

Tags: python, virtualenv, uninstallation

I don't remember how I originally installed `virtualenv`, and apparently none of `pip`, `pip3`, and `brew` are claiming it.

```
$XXX list | grep virtualenv
```

Returns nothing. XXX is pip, pip3, and brew.

But here it does return a directory:

```
$which -a virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

**So who is 'controlling' `virtualenv`? How can I uninstall it and reinstall it?**

My motivation for this is because virtualenv is pointing to a non-existing / falsely linked interpreter, and I was advised that reinstallation of `virtualenv` might mend this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
$ virtualenv my_venv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have installed `virtualenv` with `easy_install` or downloading the tar.gz file as suggested here `https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/`.

Either way, you can try to reinstall virtualenv on top of the current installation with `pip`. If that doesn't work you might need to fix the problem at the root by fixing the bad interpreter error by installing python again with brew.

virtualenv seems to be a binary at that location so you might as well remove that file from that location `/usr/local/bin/` if you have root privileges to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/virtualenv` and then `pip install virtualenv` and then everything worked again!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/virtualenv` and then `pip install virtualenv` also works for me!

Answer (score 0):

remove by

```
pip3 uninstall virtualenv
```

and install by no cache

```
pip3 install virtualenv --no-cache-dir
```